# Specific heat of mercury and water?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, metals

My doubt is , if mercury is denser than water , then why specific heat is lesser of mercury than water , means mercury heat faster than water , if mercury heat faster than water then again , why latent heat capacity of mercury is more than water , means mercury takes more  heat  to evapourate than water.

Like my assumption is that something is less denser , should heat faster and evaporated faster.

Comment: So experiment says your assumption is wrong . You can not make "assumptions " against what you know.

Comment: Okay but why so , can you explain ?? Theoretically make me explain , what going on inside during heating and evaporation , any theory??

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "heat faster".

Comment: Many of the anomalous properties of water are a consequence of its hydrogen bonds - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond#Water.

Answer (score 2):

If by "heat faster", you mean the *rate of temperature increase* of mercury is greater than water, then the reason is the thermal conductivity of mercury is greater than water. It has nothing to do with specific heat or latent heat. Moreover, given that the thermal conductivity of metals is generally greater than non metals, and that metals are generally more dense than non metals, it stands to reason that denser materials will generally "heat faster" than non metals, all else being equal.

On the other hand, if by "heat faster" you mean require less heat to raise the temperature of a *unit mass* of substance a unit degree, or to vaporize a *unit mass* of a substance, then the reason is the specific heat or latent heat of vaporization of the substance is less. The specific heat and latent heat of vaporization of mercury is less than water.

Finally, if you want to consider the heat required to raise the temperature of a *unit volume* of a substance a unit degree, i.e., the "volumetric heat capacity", or the amount of heat to vaporize a *unit volume* of a substance, i.e., the "volumetric latent heat of vaporization", then you need to take the product of the density of the substance and its specific heat and latent heat of vaporization, respectively. *If you do that, you will find that the volumetric heat capacities and volumetric latent heats of mercury and water are much closer to each other than their specific and latent heats.* See the data and calculations below.

Hope this helps.

**DATA:**

Specific heat (c):

Mercury = 0.14 kJ/kg K

Water = 4.182 kJ/kg K

Latent heat (h):

Mercury = 295 kJ/kg

Water = 2256 kJ/kg

Density ($\rho$):

Mercury = 13,600 kg/m$^3$

Water = 1000 kg/m$^3$

**CALCULATIONS**:

The volumetric heat capacity $C=\rho c$.

For mercury

(13,600 kg/m$^{3}$)(0.14 kJ/kg K) =1900 kJ/m$^3$K

For water

(1000 kg/m$^{3}$)(4.182 kJ/kg K) = 4182 kJ/m$^3$K

Volumetric latent heat $H=\rho h$

For mercury

(13,600 kg/m$^{3}$)(295 kJ/kg) = 4.012 x 10$^6$ kJ/m$^3$

For water

(1000 kg/m$^{3}$)(2256 kJ/kg) = 2.256 x 10$^6$ kJ/m$^3$

Answer (score 0):

Heat capacity *per molecule* is related to the number of different “degrees of freedom” in which a molecule can store energy. Mercury is a metallic liquid, so each mercury atom has some interaction degrees of freedom with its neighbors, as well as the translation degrees of freedom.

Water, meanwhile, is a molecule with internal degrees of freedom. Not only can a water molecule translate (which is physicist-speak for “move in a straight line”) but water molecules can also vibrate and rotate, which mercury atoms can’t.  Furthermore, the low-energy “hydrogen bonds” between water molecules make water’s intermolecular interactions richer than mercury’s.  If you add the same amount of heat to the same *number* of water molecules versus mercury atoms, the mercury atoms can *only* speed up their thermal motion, while the water molecules will squirrel away some of the new energy in their non-translational degrees of freedom. The same amount of heat among the same number of particles will raise the temperature of the mercury more. That’s what we mean when we say that water has a large “capacity for heat.”

To find heat capacity *per unit mass*, take the heat capacity *per particle* and divide by the mass of each particle. Mercury atoms are heavier than water molecules, so water wins again here.

Beware that the “latent heat” associated with a phase transition is a different creature than the heat capacity within a phase. Heat *capacity* is about temperature changes, not about evaporation.